# Python3 change key type of nested dict from string to integer

Tags: python, key

I have dict structure like this

```
      players =  {XXX:
                  {'name'         : "Admin"},
                  YYY:
                 {'name'         : "User"}
                }
```

XXX and YYY meaning the Keys are a string. I want them to be an Integer. How can I convert the keys back to an integer please?

Comment: Did `int` function help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strings `XXX` and `YYY` contain valid integer representations, you can use the following to construct a `dict` with the key values converted to integers:

```
players2 = {int(k) : v for k, v in players.items()}
```